# Can I still upload an iOS 3.2 SDK compiled app to iTunesConnect

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store-connect, application-loader

I would like to update an iPad app, that is already existing in the app store. I have compiled that app about a year ago with XCode 3.2.4 and iOS 3.2 SDK.

Is it possible/permitted to upload an adjusted version of the app, that has been compiled with iOS 3.2 SDK again? I would like to avoid compiling the app with iOS 4.3 SDK or iOS 5 SDK (if available in a few weeks), as I would have to adjust several implementation files to optimize the app for a build with the newer SDK versions.

There seems to be no clear information related to that topic in apples docs or guideslines...

Answer (score 1):

No. Apple requires apps that are uploaded to the App Store to be compiled with the latest release SDK that is available at the time.

Comment: i uploaded an universal app to app store 2 weeks ago compiled with 3.2 for iPad and 4.1 for iPhone and its got approved in first attempt

Comment: Ole, do you have any source (apple statement, doc, guideline). Thanks Aman for sharing that info.

Comment: I agree with [Ole Begemann](http://stackoverflow.com/users/116862/ole-begemann) apps need to be compiled with an iOS 4.0 SDK but you are allowed to set the `Deployment Target` to iOS 3.0 or higher. Apple will does not allow any app that target iOS 2.0 any more.

Comment: Okay so that meens that I could still compile an app store app with 4.2 or 4.3 SDK, if iOS 5 SDK is out? By the way, I just successfully uploaded an test app (compiled with iOS 3.2) with Application Loader to iTC - I expected Application Loader to detect the 3.2 Build SDK and cancel the upload, but it it didn't. Does Apple's review team check the build sdk of the binary afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to successfully bring 2 apps into the App Store, that have been compiled with a iOS 3.2 SDK without any rejection by the Apple reviewers. Apple didn't require me to use the latest Build SDK (iOS 5.0 at this time).

Comment: Interesting that you didn't need to use a recent SDK, but (and in the interests of clarity) I think you probably meant "Apple didn't require me to use the latest Build SDK (iOS 5.0 at this time)"?